# Why do the increasing sequences $x_n, y_n$, decrease to $x,y$ to show a bivariate (or univariate) cdf is right continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, philosophy, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have a problem understanding why the concept of right continuity of a cdf has to decrease a sequence $x_n$ or $y_n$ to a limiting value $x$ or $y$ respectively.

I do not understand why in this statement $x_n$ or $y_n$ has to decrease to $x$ or $y$:-

> $\mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is right continuous in both co-ordinates, i.e. if $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n \searrow y$, then $\mathbf{F}_{X_{n},Y_{n}}(x_{n},y_{n}) \searrow \mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y)$

In fact in case of univariate cdfs the sequences $x_n$ or $y_n$ increase to infinity.

Take any sequence, $y_n \nearrow \infty \\ \text{i.e. } \ y_1 \leq y_2 \leq y_3 \leq \cdots \\ \text{hence }\ \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \infty$

Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Define event $\large{{A}_{n}}$ $= (X\leq x \ \cap Y\leq y_n), n\geq 1$

Since $y_n \uparrow$, it follows that $\large A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq \cdots$

$$\therefore y_n \nearrow \infty \implies \ \huge \cup_{\small{{n=1}}}^{\small{\infty}}\large A_n =\normalsize(X\leq x \ \cap Y< \infty) $$

This can be briefed by writing

$\large A_n$ $\nearrow \underbrace{(X\leq x \ \cap Y\leq \infty)}_{\text{let's call this event }A}\\ \therefore \large A_n \nearrow A \\ \implies \large \mathbb{P} (A_n) \nearrow \mathbb{P}(A) \\ \implies \normalsize \mathbb{P}(X\leq x \ \cap Y< y_n) \nearrow \normalsize \mathbb{P}(X\leq x)$

We can now write the univariate cdf of the random variable $X$ as

$$\large\mathbf{F}_{X}{(x)} \\ = \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{X}\leq x) \\ = \mathbb{P}(\mathrm{X}\leq x \cap \mathrm{Y}<\infty) \\ = \mathbb{P}(\lim_{y \nearrow \infty} \{ \mathrm{X}\leq x \cap \mathrm{Y}\leq y\})\\ = \mathbb{P}(\lim_{n \to \infty} \{ \mathrm{X}\leq x \cap \mathrm{Y}\leq y_{n}\}), \ \textrm{ for any sequence }\ y_{n}\uparrow \infty \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(  \mathrm{X}\leq x \cap \mathrm{Y}\leq y_{n}) \\ = \lim_{y \nearrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(  \mathrm{X}\leq x \cap \mathrm{Y}\leq y ) \\ = \lim_{y \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(  \mathrm{X}\leq x \cap \mathrm{Y}\leq y ) \\ = \large \lim_{y \to \infty} \mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{X}}(  {x,y} ) $$

Similarly, taking any sequence $x_n \nearrow \infty$, fixing $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and defining another event $\large B_n$ $=(X \leq x_n \ \cap Y \leq y), n\geq 1$, we can show that $ x_n \nearrow \infty \implies \ \huge \cup_{\small{{n=1}}}^{\small{\infty}}\large B_n =\normalsize(X\leq x_n \ \cap Y\leq y) $ and $\normalsize \mathbb{P}(X\leq x_n \ \cap Y\leq y) \nearrow \normalsize \mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)$ and we can write the cdf of the random variable $Y$ as $\large \mathbf{F}_{Y}{(y)}= \large \lim_{x \to \infty} \mathbf{F}_{\mathrm{Y}}(  {x,y} )$.

So in both cases whenever we represent the univariate cdf of $X$ and $Y$, we see that the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ are going to infinity.

Also, by the properties of bivariate cdf, we have (for r.v.s $X,Y$),

1. $\forall a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2 \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{ with } \ a_1<a_2 \ \text{ and } \ b_1<b_2$,

$\mathbf{F}(a_2,b_2) - \mathbf{F}(a_2,b_1) - \mathbf{F}(a_1,b_2) + \mathbf{F}(a_1,b_1) $

2. $\forall x\in \mathbb{R} \ \lim_{y \to -\infty}\mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0 \\ \forall y\in \mathbb{R} \ \lim_{x \to -\infty}\mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y) = 0$
3. $\lim_{\\{x \to \infty \\ y \to \infty}} \mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y) = 1 $
4. $\mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is right continuous in both co-ordinates, i.e. if $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n \searrow y$, then $\mathbf{F}(x_{n},y_{n}) \searrow \mathbf{F}(x,y)$

• So my questions are

> a. Why $x_n$ or $y_n$ has to decrease to $x$ or $y$ to prove a cdf is right continuous?

> b. What happens if they increase to $x$ or $y$? Will they become left continuous?

> c. Can we say if $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n\nearrow y$ (or vice-versa) then $\mathbf{F}_{X,Y}(x,y)$ will have jump discontinuity?

Question b and c are out of my curiosity regarding the behavior of cdf in context of right continuity.

Also the following post uses a decreasing sequence of events in order to prove the right continuity of a cdf, which I specifically do not understand why.

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/how-can-i-prove-that-the-cumulative-distribution-function-is-right-continuous#:~:text=The%20distribution%20function%20F%20is,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25238/how-can-i-prove-that-the-cumulative-distribution-function-is-right-continuous#:%7E:text=The%20distribution%20function%20F%20is,).

Any help, explanations in this regards are welcome, valuable and highly appreciated.

Comment: What are $X_n$ and $Y_n$ here?  I take it $x_n$ and $y_n$ are sequences of real numbers, but are $X_n$ and $Y_n$ sequences of random variables?  Do we know anything about them, e.g. convergence properties?  Or is $F_{X_n,Y_n}$ just the same as $F_{X,Y}$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. $X_n, Y_n$ notations were a mistake by me. I removed it. I think convergence properties might be used here for $x_n, y_n$ but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a., that's just a definition of being right-continuous in both coordinates.  Another way of saying "$f$ is right-continuous in both coordinates" is "if $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n \searrow y$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n,y_n) = f(x,y)$."  That doesn't mean this is the *only* situation where $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n,y_n) = f(x,y)$.  As you pointed out, there may be some non-decreasing sequences $x_n \rightarrow x$ and $y_n \rightarrow y$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n,y_n) = f(x,y)$, but that is entirely separate from right-continuity.

The statement here is "Any cdf $F$ is right-continuous in both coordinates."  To prove that, we can show the equivalent statement "if $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n \searrow y$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(x_n,y_n) = F(x,y)$," which is why we take arbitrary sequences $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n \searrow y$.

For b., if we took any $x_n \nearrow x$ and $y_n \nearrow y$ and were able to show $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(x_n,y_n) = F(x,y)$, that would indeed show $F$ is left-continuous.  The issue is that some cdfs aren't left-continuous, so we wouldn't be able to show that whenever $x_n \nearrow x$ and $y_n \nearrow y$, we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(x_n,y_n) = F(x,y)$.  We can probably find some sequences like that, and some cdfs that are left-continuous, but we couldn't show it for every sequence and every cdf.

For c., I'm not really sure what you are asking.  I don't see how the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ relate to $F$.  For right-continuity, we take $x_n \searrow x$ and $y_n \searrow y$ and conclude $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F(x_n,y_n) = F(x,y)$, so there is a relation between the sequences and $F$.  Here, I don't see any such relation we're assuming (or trying to show).

Comment: Thank you and now the context that I was trying to understand is clear due to your nice answer. +1 from my side. Also, for the question c I was trying to know if it would make any sense (or if any conclusion can be drawn) in this regard. Thank you again for this valuable answer.